# how to get add and edit feature in admin controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-8

so basically i am working on a ecommerce admin panel, there are two links in view(add and edit) both should be redirect to same manage form.
i have already implemented the route and controller for add product but i want a edit and delete feature also which send details of that editable product so that i can edit.

//here is my admin view code, getting product detail

```
<body>
    @foreach ($data as $p)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$p['product_name']}}</td>
                <td>{{$p['product_price']}}</td>
            <td>{{$p['category']}}</td>
            <td>{{$p['seller']}}</td>
            <td>
                    
             <a  href="">Edit</a>&nbsp;
             <a  href="">Delete</a>&nbsp;
                
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
        <h4><a href='manage'>Add Product</a></h4>
    </body>
```

//here is my route

```
Route::post('manage/add',[adminController::class,'add_product']);
```

//controller for add product

```
public function add_product(Request $request){

        $add=new product;
        $add->product_name=$request->input('product_name');
        $add->product_image=$request->input('product_image');
        $add->product_price=$request->input('product_price');
        $add->category=$request->input('product_category');
        $add->seller=$request->input('product_seller');
        $add->save();

        return redirect('admin');
    }
```

//and here is my manage form

```
<form action="manage/add" id="product_manage_form" method="post"> 
                @csrf
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productInput" name='product_name' value=""  placeholder="Enter product name" required><br>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productInput" name='product_image'  value="" placeholder="Enter product image name" required><br>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productInput" name='product_price'  value="" placeholder="Enter product price" required><br>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productInput" name='product_category' value=""  placeholder="Enter product category" required><br>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productInput" name='product_seller' value=""  placeholder="Enter product seller" required><br>
                
                <div> 
                    <input type='submit' value='submit'>
                </div>
                
            </form>
```

the data should be automatically filled if it is a edit option in manage form. please help me to how can I achieve this, i am new in laravel, thanks in advance

Comment: Would you clarify question?

Comment: i want to implement as described,how to code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add additional params to route as optional id.So that same route can be used for add and edit

```
Route::post('manage/add/{id?}',[adminController::class,'add_product'])->name('manageProduct');
```

in your view add route link for edit as below

```
   <a  href="{{route('manageProduct',$p['id'])}}">Edit</a>&nbsp;
```

In controller modify method as below

```
public function add_product(Request $request,$id=null){
if(empty($id)){
  $add=new product;
} else{
    $add=product::find($id);
}
  $add->product_name=$request->input('product_name');
  $add->product_image=$request->input('product_image');
  $add->product_price=$request->input('product_price');
  $add->category=$request->input('product_category');
  $add->seller=$request->input('product_seller');
  $add->save();

    return redirect('admin');
 }
```

Comment: thank you sir but how to configure manage form so that it put details in value field,i send $product detail in edit controller to manage then i type in input tag value="{{$product['product_name']}}". now edit works well but then add option giving undefined variable error

Comment: @VinesVilla.you may need to debug which variable giving undefined.or else post entire detail in question so some one can help

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your route.php

`Route::get('manage/{id}/edit',[adminController::class,'edit_product']);`

Then

```
public function edit_product($id){
    $product = Product::where('id', $id)->first();
    return view('manage.add', ['product' => $product]);
}
```

And then you can access $product in your manage form.

Comment: thank you sir its works exactly but how to configure manage form so that it put details in value field, i type in input tag value="{{$product['product_name']}}". but then add option giving undefined variable error

Comment: you need to add @before every value